Number of solutions to underdetermined system of equations in modular arithmetic vs real or complex valued equations
I just watched this video about solving a video game puzzle using matrices defined over the integers mod 3, which essentially ended  up being a lesson about how the usual rule, that square matrices are non-invertible if and only if the determinant is zero is only true over the reals (and, I presume, by extension, the complex numbers), and the more general rule is that a square matrix is invertible if and only if the determinant has a multiplicative inverse in the relevant number system.  Which, in the context of modular arithmetic, means the determinant must not be congruent to the mod number, since the mod number is always congruent to zero.
That much I understand.  But then he ends the video by saying, "So does that mean our problem has no solution?  Well clearly not, or we wouldn't be able to progress to the next game level, which we can.  What it actually means is that there are multiple solutions, multiple ways to beat the level, such as x, y, and z."  That immediately made me think, "Oh, so the relevant matrix corresponds to a system of undetermined equations" (that's not to say that matrices in general are necessarily models of systems of equations in particular, as that's just one application).
Over the real or complex numbers, an underdetermined system of equations generally won't just have multiple solutions, but an infinite number, which can be expressed in terms of one or more parameters, depending on how many linear dependencies there are.
Is this also true for a system of underdetermined equations defined over mod n?  Or is it something more akin to the solution to trigonometric equations where the solution is often of the form "some expression" ± 2πn, which is technically an infinite number of solutions but which are all are congruent, mod 2π (and hence all such solutions belong to a single equivalence class)?

Said linear algebra works the same over any field. But $,\Bbb Z_n = $ integers $!\bmod n,$ is a field $!\iff! n$ is prime. Else $,n = ab,$ is composite so then there are nontrivial zero divisors $,ab \equiv 0,\ a,b\not\equiv 0,,$ which greatly complicates (linear) algebra. $\ \ $

First, if you have a solution to a linear system defined mod $n$ then any vector that is (coordinate-wise) congruent to that solution is also a solution. So if a solution exists, you will always have infinitely many solutions over $\mathbb Z$. But that's kind of boring, it's more interesting to look at solutions in a system of representatives mod $n$, i.e. in the ring $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$.

Let's start with the case $n=p$ prime. In this case, $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z=\mathbb F_p$ is a field, so the theory of linear algebra applies directly: If  $Ax=b$ is our linear system, then

If $\det(A)\neq0$ (in $\mathbb F_p$), then $A$ is invertible and there is a unique solution.
If $\det(A)=0$, then there are either $0$ or multiple solutions. If there are multiple, they form an affine subspace, in particular the number of solutions is a power of $p$.


If $n$ is not prime, things get more complicated. Let $n=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$ be the prime factorization. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, $$\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z\cong\prod_{i=1}^k\mathbb Z/p_i^{e_i}\mathbb Z,$$ i.e. finding solutions mod $n$ is the same as finding solutions mod $p_i^{e_i}$ for all $i$. This implies:

If $\det(A)\in\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z^\times$ (that is, if none of the $p_i$ divide $\det(A)$), then $A$ is invertible and there is a unique solution.
Otherwise, there are either $0$ or multiple solutions. The number of solutions is the product of the number of solutions mod each $p_i^{e_i}$, which is thus a divisor of $n$.

You can say more about studying solutions modulo prime powers, but I think in the context of this question this is enough for now.
